# Finding next blank row after the user inputs a specific prefix

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set amount of tag numbers in column A. The prefix to these tag numbers vary i.e "35C-1243" or "35TC-1234". Each prefix comes with a lot of tag numbers however there are some blank rows in between tag numbers for skipped tags for example it could go from "35C-1234" to "35C-1235" to "35C-1237". This would mean that I have a blank row in between "35C-1235" and "35C-1237". What I have been trying to do is create a code that would prompt the user to enter the prefix for the tag number they want to focus on and based off that prefix the next blank row should be selected however I can't get the excel to activate the blank row. Any suggestions/help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()


Dim msg As String
Dim result As Integer
Dim x As String
msg = "Would you like to find the next available tag number?"
result = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo)

If result = vbYes Then
x = Application.InputBox("Enter the part reference ")

Select Case x

    Case x = "35C"
    NextFree = Range("A:A" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
    Range("A" & NextFree).Select

    End Select
Else
Cancel = True

End If



End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your data for better understanding? Problem in your question seems much more complicated than the one you try to solve in your code.

Comment: I believe that `Range("A:A" & Rows.Count)` should just be `Range("A:A")`. Which cell _is_ selected at the end of your code?

Comment: @EganWolf I am having trouble uploading a screenshot for some reason

Comment: @FreeMan I changed the part of the code but it still did not help. Currently, their is no cell being activated at the end of the code

Comment: A) Step through your code with `F8` is it dropping into the `Select` statement? B) Is it hitting the `Case x = "35C"` section? C) _Why_ do you have a `Case` statement in there in the first place?

Comment: @FreeMan I stepped through it and it went straight to the next blank as I wanted it to do so thank you for that. Now as far as the case statement goes, there are tag numbers with a different prefix so what I want to do is be able to use the case statement to go into the next blank cell pertaining to that specific prefix as I have multiple different prefixes on these tags which all have blanks within them. Any idea on how to go about this?

Comment: Now that you've fixed things up with @EganWolf's code, you need to use `.Find()` instead of your `Select Case` statement. When you've got the prefix, use `.Find()` to find the first occurrence of it in Column A, then use your `NextFree` statement to find it starting at that row, looking down. Then check the row above to ensure you're still in the "Tag Prefix" range (i.e. you're looking for "35C", but the next blank row isn't until "38D" something.)

Comment: I have nothing to add to @FreeMan's comment. The only thing for you is that once you find first occurrence of your prefix, it will be much simpler to find next blank cell with `End(xlDown)`.

Comment: very valid point, @EganWolf!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `Select Case`. It should be `Case "35C"` instead of `Case x = "35C"`. What you do now is compare `x` to the result of `x = "35C"`, which is `True`, but `x` is not equal `True`, so this case is `False` :)

Also what @FreeMan said about `Range("A:A" & Rows.Count)` which should be `Range("A:A")`.

Comment: this helped out a lot! thank you. Can you read my reply to @Freeman and see if you have an idea on that as well? thank you